# Excel VBA command button for another worksheet

Tags: excel

thanks in advance for the potential answerer.

I have a question with excel VBA, macro.
I made a command button that runs the code when I click the button.
It works perfectly except for one function.

```
Dim N As Long, i As Long, Kount As Long
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = N To 1 Step -1
    Kount = wf.CountA(Cells(1, i).EntireColumn)
    If Kount = 1 Or Kount = 0 Then
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

This is the function that I want to use, and may because of Defining some variables, it does not work for the command button. When I run this code via macros panel, it works perfectly, but when I copy and paste it into code for the command button, it didn't work.

I hope that my English is understandable and waiting for your kind answer.

Many thanks
Always learn a lot from stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, your title suggest you want this to run on a sheet different from the one the button is on, is this correct? In that case you need to explicitly refer to that worksheet throughout your macro, otherwise it will always run on the active sheet.

Comment: Execute your code step by step from the button and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

A bit adventurous, your code, as to the syntax for Worksheetfunction and the range definition. Please try this instead.

```
Dim Kount As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long

N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = N To 1 Step -1
    Kount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i))
    If Kount < 2 Then Columns(i).Delete
Next i
```